# Automatically switch to the strongest wifi known signal

Tags: wifi

I have 2 known networks that I have signed into at my house. One is stronger at one side of the house and one is stronger at the other. Is there any way that they automatically switch to the strongest wifi signal instead of staying on one?

Comment: Write a script to check your geolocation and switch to a different network based on the location? (I'm so hacky..)